# autofill password on edittext

Tags: android, programming-languages

i'm a little blocked with this thing. I want to fill one edittext's password when the user type its login. I have the login and password on one database sqlite. I have read on android developers that it can be done with a AutocompleTextView, but i only want to fill the edittext with its password, nothing else. It Anyone knows how can i do this?¿

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create your activity with the `EditText` get a handle on it and call setText() with the password from your database.